# update mysql database from another mysql database

Tags: mysql, duplicates, sql-insert, transfer, migrate

I have two databases "old_schema" and "new_schema" and they both contain a table "new_table" with two columns "idnew_table"(This is the primary key) and "new_tablecol". Some of the data in these tables match but not all. I would like to transfer all the data from old_schema to new_schema and update new_tablecol for any entries with duplicate "idnew_table"

I tried this

```
INSERT INTO new_schema.new_table (new_tablecol) SELECT new_tablecol FROM  old_schema.new_table
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE new_tablecol = 'updated'
```

But it says there are no duplicates

Comment: You are not inserting value for the primary key column so there will be no duplicates. Can you post the show create table output for both tables?

Comment: I actually needed to insert the primary key as well and had forgotton to. that fixed it. thanks @marekful